# Node.Js Different output for the same code Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
Promise.resolve(22)
  .then((s)=> console.log('a',s))
  .then( () => {
    throw 'Oh no!';
  }).catch( err => {
    console.error( 'b', err );
  }).then( () => {
    console.log( 'c' );
  });
```

^ I am learning about async programming and I learned that .then wait for the end of the execution in a promise and is then executed, but this piece is full of .then and I am not sure of the correct order of execution.
Running this locally with NodeJs I get this output:

```
a 22
b Oh no!
c
```

However running the same code on online compilers I get different order of execution.
On one I got this:

```
a 22
c
b Oh no!
```

While on other

```
Error(s), warning(s):

b Oh no!

a 22
c
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are *one* and *other* compilers? If you have a problem, consider providing a way to replicate it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unlikely that you can get *While on other* output in chronological order if you did this properly, just because this isn't how promises work.

Comment: These "others" seem to group the output into errors / logs

Comment: The online compliers are ones I found on google http://rextester.com/l/nodejs_online_compiler and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php . Executing this on jsfiddle gives the same output as the first order (the one I got locally)

Comment: @R1ddler. Instead of using these services, why not just start your developer console in your browser to see the real result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first order you state is absolutely the only correct order. If something gives you a different order, then that thing is broken.

So maybe there's something really wrong with your 'online compiler'.

** Answers to follow-ups **

1. Every time you call `then()` it actually happens outside of the main loop. So you are correct with this statement: "I had to guess the order of execution I'd say first it resolves 22 then goes to the end of the program and then executes the .then one by one? Am I correct?".
2. You're not really 'nesting' anything, but you are chaining stuff. Every time you chain a `then()` or `catch()`, the correct order is maintained.
3. If one of the promises fails, (rejected, exception throw, etc.), it will cause every `then()` to skip until it finds a `catch()`. When it finds a `catch()` the next promise is resolved normally again.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the first order is the only correct one? Is that how .then are executed when nested? One after the other? If I had to guess the order of execution I'd say first it resolves 22 then goes to the end of the program and then executes the .then one by one? Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't specific to Node.js and will run the same way in any ES6 environment, e.g. browser console, so it doesn't make sense to compare console output from online services that run Node.js remotely with local Node.js.

```
a 22
b Oh no!
c
```

is the right order in which console output is performed, there can be no
discrepancies.

An `async..await` counterpart for this snippet that gives a better impression of control flow is:

```
(async () => {
  try { 
    let s = /* await */ 22;
    /* await */ console.log('a',s);
    throw 'Oh no!';
  } catch (err) {
    /* await */ console.error( 'b', err );
  }
  /* await */ console.log( 'c' );
})();
```

`await` statements that represent `then` and `catch` are commented because they don't affect control flow here.

[This online service](http://rextester.com/MPHN63991) waits for the script to complete (notice that execution takes 5 seconds), then prints *stderr* and *stdout* output respectively (`console.warn` and `console.error` result in *stderr* output).  *stderr* and *stdout* were logged separately. *stderr* output comes first and is titled as `Error(s), warning(s)`.